# launch custom profile from Edit button?

Tags: profile, custom-templates, contact-types

Civi 5.9.1. WordPress 5.0.3

I built a profile for my organization's staff to use when adding an Individual with a specific subtype ("Farmer"). I created a New Farmer menu item under Contacts>New Individual in the nav bar, and linked it to the Farmer profile's URL. I used the Contact Summary Layout extension to show only the fields from that profile when viewing details for an Individual of subtype Farmer. But when a user clicks the Edit button from there, the default Individual contact template appears, instead of my custom Farmer profile.

Is there any way to change this, so that editing an existing Individual of a certain subtype launches the profile created for that subtype? (I framed the question generally because we'll eventually have a few more subtypes with their own profiles that also will differ substantially from the default and from each other. But for now I'm setting aside the question of whether and how an Individual's subtype can change over time.)

While I have no coding experience outside of SQL (at which I'm fairly expert), I'm open to suggestions that go beyond the CiviCRM UI.

Many thanks!

EDIT: I'd also be keen to learn if there's a way to hide or disable the Edit button on the Contact Summary page, even if it can't be done based on subtype. Users would still have recourse to the pencil icons on that page, which should work fine given that it matches the custom profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a link but I'm not sure how to get the link to display somewhere without some customization. For example if the contact id is 2 and the profile id is 3 then this url will open the profile to edit the user:

https://your-website/civicrm/profile/edit?cid=2&gid=3&reset=1

The profile id is what you see in the url when you're on the admin page where you created the profile, and you hover over the Fields or Settings link, e.g. in this example it's the gid=3 part:
https://your-website/civicrm/admin/uf/group/field?reset=1&action=browse&gid=3

EDIT: There is a way to get to the desired page just using the UI but it's a couple steps:

1. Go Search - Find Contacts. Pick some criteria that will find your
   contact.
2. In the results list check the checkbox on the left next to
   the contact.
3. From the actions dropdown at the top of the results list, choose Update Multiple Contacts.
4. It will then redirect to a page where you pick the profile.
5. Then on the next page it will present a version of the edit form.

Comment: Thanks, Demerit. I tried that. It's helpful as an alternate edit method for my staff (and good to know about the gid), but it wouldn't prevent them from using the Edit button on the Summary page, correct? Maybe the way forward is to hide/disable that button, and then staff could use the pencil icons on the Summary page, which is identical in content to the profile. I'll edit my question accordingly. Thanks again!